# pseudo-element selector to a span element not getting applied

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am having a problem applying CSS rules to an element inside span tag when using a pseudo-element selector.

I have this HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>A Simple Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
      <p><span class="firstletter">H</span>ello World.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying to apply styles on the H letter of Hello

when I am doing this without using pseudo-element selector, like this

```
.firstletter {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

It works fine; the CSS rules are getting applied to the letter H.

But since I am learning the pseudo-element selector and trying to apply it on the letter H, the rules are not getting applied at all

```
.content:first-letter {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

But I think it should work. What is the issue here?

Comment: This [works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/56xdpuwc/) for me.  Can you update the question to a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: inline elements ignore `::first-letter` -- see the duplicate target

Answer (score 0):

The selector needs to be `.content p:first-letter`

```css
.content p:first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>A Simple Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Hello World.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Or if you need it to be more precise in the actual situation, use for example `.content > p:first-of-type:first-letter`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the selector : `first-child`

```css
.content span:first-child {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>A Simple Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
      <p><span class="firstletter">H</span>ello World.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```